# How to call a function in jquery ui spinner stop event

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I am using jquery ui spinner, I want to call a function on spinner stop event.

I do not want to call that function every stop event, only when the user stop clicking up or down arrow.

Change event works only the textbox loss the focus, I want when text box is on focus.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: _I do not want to call that function every stop event, only when the user stop clicking up or down arrow._ - can you clarify this?

Comment: yes.. want to call a function there is delay changing the values in the spinner.

Comment: for example current spinner value is 5 and incremental value  is 1 and max value would be 10.  when click up arrow   continuously three times and stopped clicking, now i want call the function not every incremental value.

Comment: check my answer, it should do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your callback to be triggered after a sequence of clicks is over, you can use `_.debounce` for that. Here is the code and the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrpxW4KgiIWEg9eu1YnV?p=preview):

```
$(function(){
  var expectedDelayBetweenClicks = 500;
  var element = $("input");

  element.spinner({
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $('.selected-value').text('Waiting...');
    },

    stop: _.debounce(function(e, ui) {
      $('.selected-value').text(e.target.value);
    }, expectedDelayBetweenClicks)
  })
});
```

This guarantees that you callback will be triggered only after several clicks, if the delay between those clicks is 500 ms. You can decrease this delay or increase it based on how fast you expect users to click the spinner.

Comment: this work for every change in the textbox. if  i want to change the text box value from 10 to 100, i want to trigger after typed 100

Comment: @thaya, check [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrpxW4KgiIWEg9eu1YnV?p=preview)

Comment: @thaya, did you check?

Comment: thanks and working fine.. I need another help there are  two methods needs to call on stop event, one method needs to call with debounce another method debounce.

Comment: another method without debounce

Comment: @thaya, if it helped you can accept this answer. Please, ask another question regarding you last question.